# RSS for torrent client: in which field does the magnet link go?

Tags: rss, bittorrent, utorrent

I'd like to read an rss of a popular torrent website and, item per item, open the linked page, grab the magnet link.

Then ... output to the user a modified version of the original RSS with the magnet link per each item.

What I want is to build an RSS adapt to be used for autodownload feature of client like bitTorrent and uTorrent.

What I've no idea is in which field/in which format to put the magnet link (or link to .torrent file for pages without magnet)

I've not found docs googling and nothing else even in the torrent site. for example in [this](http://help.bittorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/163700-how-do-i-import-torrents-from-rss-feeds-) official page about RSS and torrents, there is no info about the right place into rss feed to put the links.

Comment: see [BEP0036 Torrent RSS feeds](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0036.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it ! 
The TAG (field is a non-correct term) is `enclosure`.

I found a working RSS on Mininova. Example:

```
<enclosure url="<.torrent or magnet link>" 
     length="161034" 
     type="application/x-bittorrent" />
```

Note that length is optional and is the length of `.torrent` file if present, and not the length of what is downloaded through the torrent itself